# setOnItemClickListener will not work with the checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox

My `ListView` contains Ten Rows. Each rows contained the `CheckBox`. How would I check and uncheck the `CheckBox` using `setOnItemClickListener`

Sample Code : (it's not working for me)

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, final View v, final int position, long id ) 
    {
        Toast.makeText( this, " Position is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ) .show();
        holder.checkbox = ( CheckBox ) v.findViewById( R.id.lock_File_CheckBox );
        holder.checkbox.toggle();
    }
});
```

How do we find whether `CheckBox` is checked or unchecked?

Comment: creating holder class in activity rather than in Adapter..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the instance of Checkbox inside `onItemClick()` you need to use `setTag()` and `getTag()` for checkbox instance. You can check [`my example on my blog`](http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) that shows how we can get the instance of CheckBox inside `onItemClick()`.

After getting your CheckBox instance inside `onItemClick()` update your content of list and notify your adapter inside `onItemClick()` as,

```
if(checkbox.isChecked())
    list.get(position).setSelected(false);
else
    list.get(position).setSelected(true);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks. Please explain this code `list.get(position).setSelected(false);`

Comment: Well, `list.get(position)` will return an instance of POJO class where you are saving the state of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) for `CheckBox`

```
CheckBox repeatChkBx = ( CheckBox ) findViewById( R.id.repeat_checkbox );
repeatChkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }else
        {
            // perform logic
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @user1474868 Then [Try this](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox has oncheckedChangeListener.
        write this code in getView Function of ListView

```
Toast.makeText( this, " Position is " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ) .show();
                holder.checkbox = ( CheckBox ) v.findViewById( R.id.lock_File_CheckBox );
                holder.checkbox.toggle();


       holder.checkbox .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }else
        {
            // perform logic
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't the `position`-parameter to determine which view you have clicked. The OnItemClickListener does give you this parameter to know which item in the list has been clicked. The logic for handling this item at position X, you will have to implement.

Your solution will look something like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long arg3) {
            // mData is the Array (or some other Collection) of Checkboxes which I gave to my ListAdapter
            ((CheckBox)mData.get(position)).toggle();
        }
    });
```